# Connect to Android phone stuck in boot

Tags: data-recovery, adb

I would like to access the data from my Android phone stuck in boot. Is it possible to connect using ADB or anything any this stage?

Details:
I have a Huawei Mate 20 Pro purchased April 2019. I believe something is wrong with the charging mechanism. There has been a charging issue for several weeks now - it charged very slowly. When the phone is unplugged, it shows the red logo indicating that the battery is empty. When the phone is plugged in, it goes to the HUAWEI boot screen and gets stuck.

I took it to the Huawei repair center. In order to conduct ANY repair, they must first delete the data to comply with German law. I have not heard of such a law... but anyway... is there any hope in recovering the data before I send it off for repair?

Comment: Do you have an alternative charger you can use, which you know to be good on another device?

Comment: Basically no, the data cannot be recovered from a bricked phone. If you have TWRP installed, you could take a backup of the data, but that doesn't include photos/videos/documents.

Comment: I would say that they don't have to delete the data but they want to do so as otherwise if they mix up devices from different customers or do something other wrong they can get a penalty dues to the GDPR. Therefore this more a statement like "we are too stupid to handle our customers data correctly - therefore we eliminate the risk this is simpler and cheaper for us".

Comment: If you have already activated adb you can simply try it out. If not you can't as for enabling adb you need a fully booted device with access to it's GUI.